# Having Problems with SUMIF in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Having a bit of an issue with SUMIF in Google Sheets.

Currently, I'm pushing data from Google Analytics into a workbook. From there, I'm then taking the data and combining it to show how much traffic and how many conversions came from the source.

Specifically, I'm looking at "Google/CPC" and, when I highlight the cells for the data in one sheet, I see a sum of 92.

However, when I use the SUMIF formula, the total I'm provided with is 65.

I switched all the cells to numbers, just to confirm that it wasn't an issue there (which I figured would be the case since Sheets was automatically formatting them).

And, now I can't figure out how to get the sum to reflect the sum shown in the other sheet.

Here's the original data copied to another sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Z0D2h5yYSyMV_6fr9pRRArQXLY-Ocoe1OEWvfaLNB8/edit?usp=sharing

Specifically, I need help with cell C8 on sheet2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the formula in C8

`=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A, A8, Sheet1!D:F)`

Instead of that formula you could use

`=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A, A8, Sheet1!D:D)+SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A, A8, Sheet1!E:E)+SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A, A8, Sheet1!F:F)`

the above because SUMIF ranges should have one column or one row not multiple rows and columns.

Comment: Perfect! That did it! Thanks so much!